# Clock Schedule Once Error in class functions/methods

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

I have a class with two functions in a Kivy app. One function calls the second with Clock.schedule_once(function_name).

```
class SivaCEFBrowser(Screen):
    def back_to_login(self):
        App.get_running_app().root.current='login_screen'
        App.get_running_app().root.transition.direction='right'

    def go_to_verify(self):
        App.get_running_app().root.current='verify_screen'
        App.get_running_app().root.transition.direction='left'

    def launch_cef_browser(self):
        sys.excepthook = cef.ExceptHook  # To shutdown all CEF processes on error.
        cef.Initialize()
        cef.CreateBrowserSync(url="https://www.google.com/", window_title="Hello World!")
        cef.MessageLoop()
        cef.Shutdown()

    def trigger_browser(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.launch_cef_browser)
```

When my code runs, the trigger_browser() function is called which, in turn, invokes launch_cef_browser(). This is the error that I get:

[image]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define launch_cef_browser function like `def launch_cef_browser(self, *args)`.

The `*args` argument is being used by kivy for internal processing of the function.

Comment: Thank you. That worked. I am actually trying to embed a cefpython browser inside a Kivy screen but can't get it to work. The example listed in GitHub appears to be very lengthy and complex for a simple operation such as visiting a url. Would you be kind enough to share any advice?